# Appropriate use of validUntil and cacheDuration in metadata

Tags: saml

After reading the spec I'm unclear on the appropriate use of `validUntil` and `cacheDuration` in SAML metadata. Is there any danger in having a `validUntil` value a year or more into the future?

For example, if I am publishing a signing certificate that expires on August 1, 2018 11:00 would I structure the `validUntil` with that value so that even if the `cacheDuration` falls on a different interval the other party would refresh when the certificate expires?